# Bind RadGrid `EditItemTemplate` DropDownList inside RadComboBox `SelectedIndexChanged` event, this RadComboBox is outside of RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid, radcombobox

**HTML code:**

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlCompany" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
  DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Code"     OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged">
</telerik:RadComboBox> 

<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AccountCode" HeaderText="Account Code">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode")%>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") + " - " + Eval("AccountDescription")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAcCode" DataTextField="AccountDescription" DataValueField="AccountCodeID" runat="server"/> 
   </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

**C# code:**

```
protected void RGGSTAcCode_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
       {
          //bind dropdwon while "Add" 
          string CompanyCode = ddlCompany.SelectedValue.ToString();
          GridEditableItem item = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
          DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlAcCode");
          ddl.DataSource = GetAccCode(CompanyCode);
          ddl.DataTextField = "AccountDescription";
          ddl.DataValueField = "AccountCodeID";
          ddl.DataBind();
          ddl.Items.Insert(0, "- Select -");

          //Select particular dropdown value while "Edit"
          Label lblAcCode2 = item.FindControl("lblAcCode2") as Label;
          if (lblAcCode2.Text != "- ")
          {
             ddl.SelectedItem.Text = lblAcCode2.Text;
             ddl.SelectedValue = lblAcCode2.Text;
          }
       }

    }

protected void ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //have to bind the dropdown based on RedComboBox Item
}
```

**Requirement 1:** I want to bind RadGrid `EditItemTemplate` DropDownList inside 
RadComboBox `SelectedIndexChanged` event, this RadComboBox is outside of RadGrid.

**Requirement 2:** Want to disable "Add New" button of RadGrid with an alert msg, If RadComboBox (which is outside of RadGrid) item is not selected before clicking "Add New" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code solved both the requirements:

```
//RedComboBox 'selectedIndexChanged' event
protected void CompanyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadComboBox CompanyComboBox = fvIPRForm.FindControl("ddlCompany") as RadComboBox;

    if (CompanyComboBox.SelectedValue == null || CompanyComboBox.SelectedValue == "")
    {
        RadGrid grid = fvIPRForm.FindControl("RGGSTAcCode") as RadGrid;
        GridCommandItem cmditem = (GridCommandItem)grid.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem)[0];
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button ctrl = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)cmditem.FindControl("AddNewRecordButton");
        ctrl.Enabled = false;

        System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton btn = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)cmditem.FindControl("InitInsertButton");
        btn.Enabled = false;

        string content = "Please select company first";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Successful", "alert('" + content + "');", true);
    }
    else
    {            
        //else code here
    }
}

//Disable Account Code functionality, If company is not selected
protected void RGGSTAcCode_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "InitInsert")
    {
        RadComboBox CompanyComboBox = fvIPRForm.FindControl("ddlCompany") as RadComboBox;

        if (CompanyComboBox.SelectedValue == null || CompanyComboBox.SelectedValue == "")
        {
            e.Canceled = true;

            RadGrid grid = fvIPRForm.FindControl("RGGSTAcCode") as RadGrid;
            GridCommandItem cmditem = (GridCommandItem)grid.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem)[0];
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button ctrl = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)cmditem.FindControl("AddNewRecordButton");
            ctrl.Enabled = false;

            System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton btn = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)cmditem.FindControl("InitInsertButton");
            btn.Enabled = false;

            string content = "Please select company first";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Successful", "alert('" + content + "');", true);
        }
    }
}
```